# Change Trello authentication for Google Apps auth?

Tags: trello

I am logging into Trello the *old way* with login+password. Is-it possible to transform this authentication for my existing Trello account into a Google Apps authentication instead? I suspect that this feature require the *Business Class* subscription of Trello, but I am not even sure that it would work.

Comment: Try logging in with your google apps account; it'll say that it hasn't seen that ID before, and will give you a chance to associate it with an existing account (your username/password one)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change how you log in and you do not need a Business Class subscription.  I switched from Google Apps login to email address login, added my new email address in Trello, attaching it to my Google address.

IF your email address is the same as your Google Apps email address, take these steps:

1. Log out of Trello and log out of all your Google Accounts
2. Log into your Google Account.
3. Go to https://trello.com/login
4. Click the button to log in with your Google Account Trello will say
   (paraphrased) "do you want to associate it with an existing
   account"?
5. Choose the option to merge/use with an existing account. This will
   bring up the Trello login page.
6. Enter your email address and your existing Trello password.
7. You'll now be logged into the Trello account and login will be
   associated with Google as well.

A similar help page can be found here: 
http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1335753-switching-your-user-account-with-google-auth